# retrofit get request with dynamic path

Tags: android, retrofit

I have two APIs -

One to search for a phone number (let's say http://example.com/api/?phone=1234567890) which returns the **id** of the person associated with that phone number

And another (http://example.com/api/con/**id**/) to fetch for contact details.

Basically, in the second call, I have to include the id that is returned in the first call.

My question is how do I do this?

I've come till here in my code, but I couldn't find anything beyond this for my situation.

```
public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("/con/")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a change in dynamic path so if you are trying to call it from local server you need to create .htaccess file with following rules:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^api/con/([0-9]+)/?$ RestController.php?phone=single&id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)number=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^api/?$ RestController.php?phone=all&no=%1 [NC,L]
```

This will redirect your server based on the query parameters and URL.

```
 public interface RequestInterface 
 {
   BASE_URL = "http://example.com" 
   @GET("/api")
   Call<YourFetchResponse> getPhoneDetails(@Query("api_key") String apiKey,@Query("phone") String phone);

   @GET("/api/con/{id}")
   Call<YourIdResponse> getIdDetails(@Query("api_key") String apiKey,@Path("id") String id);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    Call<YourFetchResponse> call = RequestInterface.getPhoneDetails(API_KEY,PHONE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<YourFetchResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YourFetchResponse> call, Response<YourFetchResponse> response)
        {

        Call<YourIdResponse> call1 = RequestInterface.getIdDetails(API_KEY, response.body().getId);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<YourIdResponse>()
        {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<YourIdResponse> call,  Response<YourIdResponse> response)
           {....}       
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<YourFetchResponse> call, Throwable t)
          {....}

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YourFetchResponse> call, Throwable t)
        {....}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @Path annotation.

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    BASE_URL = "http://example.com/api/";

    @GET("con/{id}")
    Call<YourFetchResponse> contactFetch(@Path("id") String id);

    @GET("")
    Call<YourIdResponse> contactId(@Query("phone") String phone);

}
```

Good luck there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface RequestInterface {

 @GET("serviceURL")
Call<JSONResponse> getPhoneDetails(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

 @GET("serviceURL")
Call<JSONResponse> getIdDetails(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

}
```

onResponse of First service call second service.